# Could not install package Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging

Tags: firebase, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm trying to install the latest version of *Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging* (as of today: *60.1142.1*) in the Xamarin.Android project of my Xamarin.Forms solution.

I get this error:

```
Attempting to gather dependency information for package 'Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging.60.1142.1' with respect to project 'prova.Droid', targeting 'MonoAndroid,Version=v7.1'
GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration3-gz-semver2/xamarin.firebase.messaging/index.json
OK https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration3-gz-semver2/xamarin.firebase.messaging/index.json 137ms
Total number of results gathered : 20
Gathering dependency information took 157,61 ms
Summary of time taken to gather dependencies per source :
https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json -   156,72 ms
Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging.60.1142.1' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
Resolving dependency information took 0 ms
Resolving actions to install package 'Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging.60.1142.1'
Resolved actions to install package 'Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging.60.1142.1'
Retrieving package 'Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging 60.1142.1' from 'nuget.org'.
GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/xamarin.firebase.messaging/60.1142.1/xamarin.firebase.messaging.60.1142.1.nupkg
OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/xamarin.firebase.messaging/60.1142.1/xamarin.firebase.messaging.60.1142.1.nupkg 540ms
Acquiring lock for the installation of Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging 60.1142.1
Acquired lock for the installation of Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging 60.1142.1
Installing Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging 60.1142.1.
Completed installation of Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging 60.1142.1
For adding package 'Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging.60.1142.1' to project 'prova.Droid' that targets 'monoandroid71'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Package 'Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging.60.1142.1' does not exist in project 'prova.Droid'
Package 'Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging.60.1142.1' does not exist in folder '/Users/g.paradiso/Projects/prova/packages'
Executing nuget actions took 592,47 ms
Could not install package 'Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging 60.1142.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'MonoAndroid,Version=v7.1', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
```

I'm following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/push-notifications/azure) guide and it says that you need to use version *57.1104.0-beta1* and it works, but why can't I use the latest version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Could not install package 'Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging 60.1142.1'. You
>   are trying to install this package into a project that targets
>   'MonoAndroid,Version=v7.1', but the package does not contain any
>   assembly references or content files that are compatible with that
>   framework.

In short it means a compatibility issue, read it few times if needed till you get it.
In order to solve this issue check the dependencies of 'Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging 60.1142.1' NuGet package [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging/). It clearly states `MonoAndroid 8.0` when you have a `MonoAndroid 7.1`.

So you can either use an older version of `Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging` (not recommended) or update your target framework in the Android project to 8.0.